# Getting "$ is not defined" in a script loaded after jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code that first loads jQuery then a script that uses the $ syntax. But I always get

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

First I thought it was because the async attribute on the script tag was set to async, but it doesn't make a difference.

**Html**:

```
<script async="false" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>

<script async="async" src="/SCRIPT/Creator/Creator.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>
```

**Creator.js**:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  function CloseModalBackground() {
    ....
  }
});

//# sourceMappingURL=Creator.js.map
```

Live snippet demonstrating the problem:

```html
<script async="false" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>

<script>
// jQuery *should* be defined by now, right But no:
console.log(typeof $);
</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ dev-tools console to see if the scripts are loading and in what order

Comment: `async` is the problem

Comment: Have you tried removing the async attribute **entirely**? I don't think the false actually makes it false. It just cares if it's there.

Comment: @zero298 yeah you're right. I removed the whole attribute and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the async attribute on the script tag worked for me.

edit: And yes, regardless of what value assigned to async attribute, once it is present, then the script will be called asynchronously.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Hello World!");
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! I thought I could set async="false", but I guess I have to remove the attribute instead

Answer (score 4):

To clarify *why* removing the `async` attribute works, it's a **boolean attribute**, and, per the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. **The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.** If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So `async=false`, where `async` is a boolean attribute, still means that the boolean attribute is truthy, since the attribute exists. Whatever is contained in the attribute doesn't *really* matter, but to avoid confusion, if it has a value at all, the value *should* be either the name of the attribute or the empty string.

<s>[MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) on this is misleading.</s> Fixed, thanks Andrew-Cotterell. The only way to actually make `async` to be considered to be false is to make sure the attribute doesn't exist at all on the script element.